# console.groupCollapsed("Application Log"); - what is it?

Tags: config

If I "View source" in my browser I get a bunch of stuff in the end of my html output. It starts with console.groupCollapsed("Application Log");.

I guess this is something Craft does automatically. Is it possible to turn it off when I launch my site?

Answer (score 6):

This is something Craft only shows if your site is in devMode (http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode).

If you use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools for instance, it shows you a performance and error log.

By disabling devMode, it disappears. Do this by setting 'devMode' => false into your craft/config/general.php.

Answer (score 2):

Just turn off [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) in your general config:

```php
return array(
    'devMode' => false,
);
```

Also check out the knowledge-base article: [What does Dev Mode do?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode)